# Alternative to Huge Codeigniter session data

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, optimization

I have seen many similar questions on the overflow, but none of them really addressed my scenario hence I am opening this question.

I am working on a project where there is database of thousands of mp3 tracks and mixes. Each mp3 file has an id and associated information on database.  Now a shopping cart is being build in a way that user can select tracks and add to the cart. When a track is being added to cart its id is stored in the session and this works fine.

Now the problem arrives when there is large number of id's stored in a session. A session being a cookie [codeignitor] , I know it has 4kb of storage.

What will be the best practice to get this data preserved? I know that I have to change my strategy and move out of using session.

I tried using database [mysql], its not only slower but also has several issues, like each new user need to have a row added to database tables, how to clear these tables after use.. etc etc.

I tried using memcached but I believe that is not the right choice since the data that I am trying to store is not that huge. Also memcached has several issues on windows platform, provided I am not sure if the client will deploy it on a linux / windows server.

I need a native cross platform solution. I have done quiet a lot of research and did not find a reliable solution yet.

I use codeigniter framework, hence you can suggest any PHP or codeigniter solutions, thanks much.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to store the actual contents of the cart in the database, keyed by session or user name, and only carry the minimal session information around in the cookie?

Comment: I learned that the issues is caused by Codeignitor session and not the native PHP session. Since Codeignitor session is basically a cookie. It has all limitations of a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a native PHP session is the right way to move, as the fellow users answered a php session stores only id on to cookie, But codeignitor behaves differently, it stores all the data on to cookie and this is where the catch is.

Moving on to normal PHP session was a pain because I have to change the codes allover the project. After a little research and testing I have come to a conclusion that [Native Session library for CI][1]

[1]: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session by Derek Jones is an awesome alternative to use PHP sessions over CI with the same CI session functions and syntax.

So to conclude , Either use PHP sessions from the scratch or use this library as an alternative to overcome CI session size Limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about storing things "in the session" so I assume you're using PHP's session handler, not setting cookies individually.

In this case, the session storage is all done on the server side, so a 4k limit does not apply. Take a look at your http headers during a request, and you will see only something like this:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1234abcde56789f
```

This session ID refers to a file (typically stored in a directory, e.g. `/var/lib/php/session/` on RHEL distros) which contains the actual data as a serialized PHP object.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try setcookie() function in php?
you can store as much amount of data you want in the cookie,and store the refrence to the session in database!
hope you will understand my answer!

Comment: My question is specific , I know how to set a session. The problem here is large session data. If you read more about session, you can understand that its simply cookies and they have limitations.

Answer (score 0):

what miken32 is saying is correct. And if you are using Codeigniter, then set up a session database table and use codeigniter sessions. if you use a db table then **its just an id which is set on the cookie**. be sure and start with the official codeigniter session db table so it works properly.

codeigniter session class has built in 'garbage collection'.

all explained here, scroll down for the database portion: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I don not totally agree to that statement, A codeignitor session is a cookie.. read "What is Session Data?" in the link that you provided. Hence a codeignitor session has all the limitations of a cookie. Not only id's but also the variables are stored in user cookie when you use a CI session class.

Comment: You are correct IF you do not use a database table which is the default. BUT if you use a database table then only the session ID is stored in the cookie. direct quote: "Once enabled, the Session class will store session data in the DB." IMPORTANT - besides setting up the correct db table you must set the session values in your config/config.php file.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the statement. However the reality is far fro it. by enabling the database, it is not only storing the session data in cookie but also in database. Th purpose of database is only for session validation. By encrypting the session I am adding additional burden on the session because encrypted session has more size than the normal session. While my requirement is to  store large data in CI session.

Comment: I am trying out CI Native session class that uses PHP native sessions but uses same CI syntax. Probably that might be a right solution.